# CommandEventArgs null value in OnCommand event handler for a Custom WebControl implementing IButtonControl

Tags: asp.net, events, listview, web-controls

I am very sorry for the long title but I really didn't know how to be more self explaining than this.

The problem I have is this:
I designed and developed a WebControl which consists in a simple set of elements that, combined togheter in the simplest way, defines a custom button. This control is the one I would like to use in my web application instead of Button and LinkButton control (reasons mainly rely on graphic and visual functionalities).
In order to let the webcontrol behave like a button, it also implements the IButtonControl interface so that all elements needed by the framework in order to handle events and similar stuff are well provided.
Well, this button I called **BoxButton** works fine everytime it is used, instead for one thing.

Sorry for the long prelude, now we can go straight to the real problem:
In a page I have a ListView and in the listview I have the InsertItemTemplate enabled.
Well this insertitemtemplate works fine when the OnItemInsert is fired by pressing a button inside the template (a button, an ordinary button control).
Well, I sure wanted to place my BoxButton in place of the ordinary one. When I do this I have a problem.
The handler function is this:

```
protected void Insert_BoxButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CommandName == "Insert") {
        // Do something     
    }
}
```

Typically, the e object is able to give information to the developer in order to locate all data to be inserted. These data are available when I use a normal button, but when using a BoxButton it is null!
Well, you could tell me that, when I defined my BoxButton implementing the IButtonControl interfaces, I had to manage with both the two events in the interface (dealing woth button pressure: Click and Command) and manage with the problem of providing CommandEventArgs. But how to do this?
Is there a solution to my problem? How can I manage eventargs? I sense that probably this is a very low programming issue... maybe there is much to do.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Andry